# Excel iteration over rows only if matching value in column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

I want to automatically produce two new tables, one containing only the values where `match_this` is `"Option 1"` and the other where it is `"Option 2"`. I can do `=IF(B2="Option 1",A2,"")` to get this:

[image]

However, as expected, this leaves empty cells in between (unless I sort the original table). I would like, instead, to obtain something like this:

[image]

How can this be done?

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using? In Excel 365, the Filter function will do exactly what you want.

Comment: @user171780  ,,, I'm feeling sorry to say that the way U are working is WRONG ,,,,, the formula in `D2 =if(b2="Option 1", A2,"")` ,,, will print 'A' but if B2 is `Option 2` !! Since Column B has Drop Down may contain more OPTIOS ,,, like Option 1, Option 2 or Option 3 also , in that case the formula will not return the expected results. U need to create a Lookup Table for Values for their related options to work !!  [Check this,,,](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) ☺

Answer (score 0):

Like Paul said, use **filter function** as below. Adjust your range and do the same for option_2.

```
=FILTER($A$1:$A$6,$B$1:$B$6="Option 1")
```

This will spill the result which are true to the condition without blank cells.